# Variable Substitution for Calculating Derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I notice that when calculating derivative, it seems possible to (1) separate the function into the combination of several parts by substituting the target variable $x$ with different versions like $x_1,x_2,\cdots$, (2) calculate the partial derivatives w.r.t. $x_i$, (3) sum them together by removing the subscript to get the final correct derivative w.r.t. $x$.

To illustrate, fist consider a simple case of addition:

> Given $f_1(x) = p(x) + q(x)$ and $f_2(x_1,x_2)=p(x_1)+q(x_2)$, then $\frac{df_1}{dx}=\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1}|_{x_1=x}+\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}|_{x_2=x}$

An example is $f(x)=x + \sin(x)$.

A general case is:

> Given $f_1(x) = h(p_1(x),\cdots,p_n(x))$ and $f_2(x_1,\cdots,x_n) = h(p_1(x_1),\cdots,p_n(x_n))$, then $\frac{df_1}{dx}=\sum_i\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_i}|_{x_i=x}$

So I want to know whether the general case is true? How to prove it?

Comment: It is indeed true that $\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)+g(x)) = \frac{d}{dx}f(x)+\frac{d}{dx}g(x)$ providing that the right-hand side exists.  You can prove it with careful use of $\epsilon,\delta$ in the limit definition of derivatives and then extend to the more general finite sum using induction

Comment: Hi @Henry I know how to prove the finite sum case, which is quite obvious. But the general case is not about just summation, which could be any function. Is it still effective to use the basic $\epsilon, \delta$ to prove it?

Comment: Well, if $n=\infty$, you also need to worry about the left-hand side existing and the sum on right-hand side converging

Comment: @Henry Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have that $f_1(x)=f_2(x,x,...,x)$. This is, $f_2$ composed with $x\mapsto (x,x,...,x)$.

The [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Multivariable_case) tells you that $$\frac{df_1}{dx}(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{df_2}{dx_i}(x,x,...,x)\cdot \frac{dx}{dx}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{df_2}{dx_i}(x,x,...,x)$$

Comment: Yes, it should be so simple using the chain rule for multivariates. Thank you!